# Php - Doesn't Return Json Encode

Tags: php, mysql, json

I need help.(sorry my english)
I have this code in php: (in my xampp v3.2.1).

```
header('Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8'); 
$query="SELECT name,...... FROM students";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $resultArray[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($resultArray);
var_dump($resultArray);
```

In my computer with xampp, The echo json_enconde and var_dump returns something, but in other server, with `php >5.2` only returns var_dump.
What can be the problem?

I have another php, with several php functions `(ftp_size($conn_id, $file);`
`ftp_mdtm($conn_id, $file);`,....  and the json_enconde returns in my computer and in the other server. I think that my problem is between the query and the`json_encode`, because in the other php the json returns results.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: Do you get anything at all, or just a blank page?

Comment: Maybe it's an encoding issue. Are both your development and production DB/tables using the same encoding? Are you using the correct encoding options for `json_encode()`?

Comment: With echo json_encode blank page, using var_dump the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

check for result (your select could generate error)

```
header('Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8'); 
$query="SELECT name,...... FROM students";

$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
 echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
  exit;
}


while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   $resultArray[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($resultArray);
var_dump($resultArray);
```

try also

```
var_dump(json_encode($resultArray));
```

and

```
$tmp  = json_encode($resultArray);
echo $tmp;
```

Comment: With echo json_encode blank page, using var_dump the correct result.